# javascript array input user and average calculation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this problem to solve.
It sounds maybe simple but I am a total beginner.
here is my code so far but there is only one window that appears when I run it.
Thank you for your advices and help

```
var years= prompt("Enter the number of years: "); // Number of years
var rainFall = new ArrayList();

while (years < 1) {

    alert("Invalid. Enter 1 or greater: ");
    years =prompt("Enter a year: ");
}

for (var y = 1; y <= years; y++) {

    for (var m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++) {

        alert("Year " + y + " month " + m + ": ");
        monthRain = prompt("enter rainfall for a month ");
        rainfall.add(monthRain);
    }
}

 alert("\nNumber of months: " + (years * NUM_MONTHS) + "Total rainfall: " + calculateTotalRainFall(rainFall) + " inches" + "Average monthly rainfall: " + calculateAverageRainFall(rainFall) + " inches");
```

Comment: Hi, try changing rainfall.add(monthRain); to rainfall.push(monthRain);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    Array.prototype.sum = function() {
      var total = 0;
      for(var i in this) {
        var i = parseFloat(this[i]);
        if(i>=0) {
          total += i;
        }
      }
      return total;
    };

    Array.prototype.avg = function() {
      var avg = (this.length>0)? parseFloat(this.sum()/this.length) : 0;
      avg = parseFloat(parseInt(avg*100)/100);
      return avg;
    };

    var years = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of years: ")); // Number of years

    var rainFall = [];

    while (years < 1) {
      alert("Invalid. Enter 1 or greater: ");
      years = parseInt(prompt("Enter a year: "));
    }

    var NUM_MONTHS = 12;
    for (var y = 1; y <= years; y++) {
      for (var m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++) {
        alert("Year " + y + " month " + m + ": ");

        var monthRain = parseFloat(prompt("enter rainfall for a month "));
        if(monthRain>=0) {
          rainFall.push(monthRain);
        }
      }
    }

 if(years<1) years = 0;
 alert("\nNumber of months: " + (years * NUM_MONTHS) + "   Total rainfall: " + rainFall.sum() + " inches" + "   Average monthly rainfall: " + rainFall.avg() + " inches");
```

**OR:**

```js
    function sumArray (items) {
      var total = 0;
      for(var i in items) {
        var i = parseFloat(items[i]);
        if(i>=0) {
          total += i;
        }
      }
      return total;
    };

    function avgArray(items) {
      var sum = sumArray(items);
      var avg = (items.length>0)? parseFloat(sum/items.length) : 0;
      avg = parseFloat(parseInt(avg*100)/100);
      return avg;
    };

    var years = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of years: ")); // Number of years

    var rainFall = [];

    while (years < 1) {
      alert("Invalid. Enter 1 or greater: ");
      years = parseInt(prompt("Enter a year: "));
    }

    var NUM_MONTHS = 12;
    for (var y = 1; y <= years; y++) {
      for (var m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++) {
        alert("Year " + y + " month " + m + ": ");

        var monthRain = parseFloat(prompt("enter rainfall for a month "));
        if(monthRain>=0) {
          rainFall.push(monthRain);
        }
      }
    }

 if(years<1) years = 0;
 alert("\nNumber of months: " + (years * NUM_MONTHS) + "   Total rainfall: " + sumArray(rainFall) + " inches" + "   Average monthly rainfall: " + avgArray(rainFall) + " inches");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is far from what I have learned in class now I am not supposed to use function yet. Just basic pseudocode

Comment: sorry I meant to not use function but I keep your answers for my next works. Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

try changing rainfall.add(monthRain); to rainfall.push(monthRain);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your core mistake was using the **Java ArrayList** class, when you should have been using the **JavaScript Array** class. Keep in mind that Java and JavaScript are not related (the name is confusing, yes).

If you change `new ArrayList()` to `new Array()`, and `rainfall.add` to `rainFall.push` (note the capitalization change as well), then it seems to work.

If you have access to a JavaScript console inspector (accessible in Chrome, for instance, with ctrl-shift-J), you can look for the JS errors that occur in your code, such as the error encountered when `ArrayList` couldn't be found.

Fixed below. I've also added the missing NUM_MONTHS constant (which I assume you had elsewhere).

```
var NUM_MONTHS = 12;
var years= prompt("Enter the number of years: "); // Number of years

// CHANGE: use "Array", not "ArrayList". You could also use "var rainFall = [];", which I find
var rainFall = new Array();

while (years < 1) {

    alert("Invalid. Enter 1 or greater: ");
    years =prompt("Enter a year: ");
}

for (var y = 1; y <= years; y++) {

    for (var m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++) {

        alert("Year " + y + " month " + m + ": ");
        monthRain = prompt("enter rainfall for a month ");
        // CHANGE: use "push()" method of Array, and use camelCase for variable name consistency
        rainFall.push(monthRain);
    }
}

alert("\nNumber of months: " + (years * NUM_MONTHS) + "Total rainfall: " + calculateTotalRainFall(rainFall) + " inches" + "Average monthly rainfall: " + calculateAverageRainFall(rainFall) + " inches");
```